# Finding cluster centroid or ".means_" with sklearn.cluster.SpectralClustering

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science

I have a an unlabeled data set that I am trying to cluster with a variety of clustering algorithms.

I am successful in being able to find the centroids/"mean of each mixture component" in sklearn.mixture.GaussianMixture using .means_. In my code I am then taking the point that is closest to the means to get a representative sample at each cluster.

I want to do this same thing with SpectralClustering, but I don't see a ".means_" method or some method to get the centroid of each cluster. This may be a result of my misunderstanding of how spectral clustering works or just a lack of features in this library.

As an example I would like to do:

```
sc = SpectralClustering(n_components=10, n_init=100)
sc.fit(data)

closest, _ = pairwise_distances_argmin_min(sc.means_, data)
```

But of course SpectralClustering doesn't have a .means_ method.

Thanks for any help on this.

Answer (score 0):

Centroid are used for the KMean algorithm. For spectal clustering, the algorithm only store the affinity matrix and the labels obtained from the algorithm.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like a lack of algorithmic understanding. After doing a bit more research, the affinity matrix just seems like a straight similarity matrix.  

I'm not totally sure how to represent an "average sample" from each cluster in this form. Something a bit expensive might be taking all the samples in a given label and averaging each of their values to produce a "representative" sample. I'll keep thinking.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter if Spectral Clustering (or any other clustering algorithm) uses the cluster centers or not!

**You can compute the centroid of any cluster!** It is the **mean** of the elements in that cluster (well, there actually is a constraint, that the dataset itself allows the notion of mean).

So, compute the clusters using Spectral Clustering. For each cluster, compute the mean of the elements inside it (as is, the mean on every dimension for a cluster comprised of *m* n-dimensional elements).